# How to config default security domain for Open eHealth IPF?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

Here is **Apache Camel 2.18.4** implemented **Open eHealth Integration Platform 3.3.0** for **XDS.b** Where **Document Consumer** performing following query from **XDS.b Registry** using **JUnit** test cases as following:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = BootstrapApplication.class)
public class GetDocumentsQueryTest implements HL7V3Constraint {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GetDocumentsQueryTest .class);

    @EndpointInject(uri = "xds-iti18://ihexds.nist.gov:12090/tf6/services/xdsregistryb")
    private ProducerTemplate producer;

    @Test
    public void query() throws Exception {
        GetDocumentsQuery query = new GetDocumentsQuery();
        String approved = AvailabilityStatus.APPROVED.getQueryOpcode();
        QueryRegistryTransformer transformer  = new QueryRegistryTransformer();
        EbXMLAdhocQueryRequest ebxmlRequest = transformer.toEbXML(new QueryRegistry(query));
        ebxmlRequest.addSlot(QueryParameter.DOC_ENTRY_STATUS.getSlotName(), StringUtils.join(new String[]{"('", "')"}, approved));
        ebxmlRequest.addSlot(QueryParameter.DOC_ENTRY_PATIENT_ID.getSlotName(), "'0becc4deeb6042a^^^&1.3.6.1.4.1.21367.2005.13.20.3000&ISO'");
        ebxmlRequest.setReturnType(XDSReturnType.LeafClass.getOpcode());
        ebxmlRequest.setHome("urn:oid:1.19.6.24.109.42.1.3");

        AdhocQueryRequest  adhocRequest = (AdhocQueryRequest) ebxmlRequest.getInternal();
        AdhocQueryResponse adhocResponse = producer.requestBody(adhocRequest, AdhocQueryResponse.class);
        EbXMLQueryResponse30 ebxmlResponse = new EbXMLQueryResponse30(adhocResponse);


        String requestId            = adhocResponse.getRequestId();
        BigInteger totalResultCount = adhocResponse.getTotalResultCount();
        String status               = ebxmlResponse.getStatus().getOpcode30();
        log.info("RequestId: {}, Status: {}, TotalResultCount: {}", requestId, status, totalResultCount);

        if(Status.FAILURE == ebxmlResponse.getStatus()){
            //TODO
        }

        if(Status.SUCCESS == ebxmlResponse.getStatus()){
            log.info("Query Success: {}", ebxmlResponse.getStatus().getOpcode30());
        }
    }
}
```

Causes following error those were may be belongs to **Syslog (ATNA Audit)**, unable to fix

```
org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.nodeauth.NoSecurityDomainException: No DEFAULT Security Domain available for host ovh3.ihe-europe.net and port 3202
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.nodeauth.SecurityDomainManager.getSecurityDomain(SecurityDomainManager.java:201)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.nodeauth.handlers.AbstractSecureSocketHandler.getSocket(AbstractSecureSocketHandler.java:116)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.sender.TLSSyslogSenderImpl.getTLSSocket(TLSSyslogSenderImpl.java:179)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.sender.TLSSyslogSenderImpl.sendAuditEvent(TLSSyslogSenderImpl.java:140)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.queue.SynchronousAuditQueue.doSend(SynchronousAuditQueue.java:43)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.queue.AbstractAuditMessageQueue.sendAuditEvent(AbstractAuditMessageQueue.java:65)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.queue.SynchronousAuditQueue.sendAuditEvent(SynchronousAuditQueue.java:26)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.IHEAuditor.audit(IHEAuditor.java:240)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.XDSAuditor.auditQueryEvent(XDSAuditor.java:92)
    at org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.XDSConsumerAuditor.auditRegistryStoredQueryEvent(XDSConsumerAuditor.java:110)
    at org.openehealth.ipf.commons.ihe.xds.iti18.Iti18ClientAuditStrategy.doAudit(Iti18ClientAuditStrategy.java:34)
    at org.openehealth.ipf.commons.ihe.xds.iti18.Iti18ClientAuditStrategy.doAudit(Iti18ClientAuditStrategy.java:26)
    at org.openehealth.ipf.commons.ihe.ws.cxf.audit.AuditResponseInterceptor.process(AuditResponseInterceptor.java:155)
    more ...
```

Would you please help us to configure **Default Security Domain** for **IPF**? It would be appreciable if any body guide us to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the configuration of `atnaModuleContext`, `atnaTlsConfig` for **IPF Default Security Domain** as following:

```
<bean id="atnaModuleContext" class="org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.context.AuditorModuleContext" factory-method="getContext">
    <property name="queue">
        <bean class="org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.queue.SynchronousAuditQueue"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="atnaTlsConfig" class="org.openhealthtools.ihe.atna.auditor.AuditorTLSConfig" init-method="init">
    <constructor-arg ref="atnaModuleConfig"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="atnaProperties"/>

    <property name="securityDomainName" value="_DEFAULT_"/>
</bean>

<bean id="atnaModuleConfig" factory-method="getConfig" factory-bean="atnaModuleContext">
    <property name="auditEnterpriseSiteId"    value="dev.chorke.org"/>
    <property name="auditSourceId"            value="dev.chorke.org"/>
    <property name="auditRepositoryHost"      value="188.165.194.55"/>
    <property name="auditRepositoryPort"      value="3202"/>
    <property name="auditRepositoryTransport" value="TLS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="atnaProperties" class="java.util.Properties" >
    <constructor-arg>
        <props>
            <prop key="https.ciphersuites">SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStore">${user.home}/.chorke/jks/2222.jks</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStore">${user.home}/.chorke/jks/2222.jks</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword">storepasswd</prop>
            <prop key="javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword">storepasswd</prop>
            <prop key="https.protocols">TLSv1</prop>
        </props>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

It would be resolve the issue (Tested on **MacOS Sierra**). Let's us info if you are succeed on other platform like **Windows 7, 8, 10**.